# Multiplying a 2D numpy array with every row of a 2D numpy array (Without using for loop)

Tags: arrays, numpy, matrix-multiplication, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

I have two 2D numpy arrays as shown below

Matrix_A is a 2D array of shape(3,3)
Matrix_B is a 2D array of shape(9,3)

```
Matrix A = [[ 0. -1.  0.]
            [ 1.  0.  0.]
            [ 0.  0.  1.]]


Matrix_B = [[0.5 0.5 0.5]
            [1.5 0.5 0.5]
            [2.5 0.5 0.5]
            [0.5 1.5 0.5]
            [1.5 1.5 0.5]
            [2.5 1.5 0.5]
            [0.5 2.5 0.5]
            [1.5 2.5 0.5]
            [2.5 2.5 0.5]]

Matrix_C = Matrix multiply A and B (preferably numpy dot)  # Need the shape of the matrix to be (9,3)
print(Matrix_C)
```

For the above case the answer for Matrix_C will be

```
Matrix_C = [[-0.5  0.5  0.5]
            [-0.5  1.5  0.5]
            [-0.5  2.5  0.5]
            [-1.5  0.5  0.5]
            [-1.5  1.5  0.5]
            [-1.5  2.5  0.5]
            [-2.5  0.5  0.5]
            [-2.5  1.5  0.5]
            [-2.5  2.5  0.5]]
```

The above value for Matrix_C was obtained using a for loop

```
Matrix_C = np.zeros_like(len(Matrix_B))

for i in range(len(Matrix_B)):
    Matrix_C[i] = np.dot(Matrix_A,Matrix_B[i])


print(Matrix_C)
```

**I would like Matrix_A to be multiplied with every row of Matrix_B.**

**Without using For loop** . By introducing numpy newaxis and numpy broadcasting methods is it possible to achieve the value for Matrix_C that I obtained using for_loop.

Looking forward for some response.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by matrixA * MatrixB[0] their dimensions are 3x3 and 1x3 so they don't multiply like that they only multiply with MatrixB[0] * MatrixA and so on for the other lines which is fairly easy to do with linear algebra

Comment: Hi @jimakr, I have edited my question and have added the output of Matrix C.. Would that be useful for you for helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so what you do require from the explanation you added is for every row of MatrixB to do Matrix A * Matrix B[0] ,..., Matrix A * Matrix B[n].
Remember when multiplying matrices the order of the multiplication is important.

Essentialy this is equlevant to (Matrix A* (Matrix B )^T)^T ( ^T meaning the transpose of the matrix). In numpy code it can be done like this assuming the matrices are numpy arrays

```
matrixC = MatrixA.dot(MatrixB.T).T
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try the code:

```
Matrix_A = np.concatenate((Matrix_A, Matrix_A, Matrix_A), axis=0)
Matrix_C = Matrix_A * Matrix_B
```

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your reply. I would like to multiply Matrix_A with Matrix_B[0], Matrix_B[1] ... Matrix_B[n]. n is the number of rows of Matrix_B.

Comment: I have edited my question for your better understanding